# Is there any way to stop the inheritance from resource group to resources and apply read-only locks to virtual machine disks of Azure using python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine

With the below python code, I'm able to lock a resource group and its resources get the lock inherited.

Is there any way to stop the inheritance to resources and apply read-only locks to virtual machine disks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create locks to virtual machine disks, please refer to the following sample

1. Create lock for one disk

```
compute_client=get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
lock_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ManagementLockClient)

disk = compute_client.disks.get(resource_group_name='testLinux', disk_name='testLinux_OsDisk_1_41c3d0e2e7b74dcca653b4e058a9332f')
lock_client.management_locks.create_or_update_by_scope(scope=disk.id,lock_name='DeleteLock',parameters={'level' : LockLevel.can_not_delete})
```

[image]

2. Create lock for all disk in one subscription

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ManagementLockClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.locks.models import LockLevel

compute_client=get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
lock_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ManagementLockClient)

disks = compute_client.disks.list()

for disk in disks:
    lock_client.management_locks.create_or_update_by_scope(scope=disk.id,lock_name='DeleteLock',parameters={'level' : LockLevel.can_not_delete})
```

---

*****update*****

If you want to get azure vm linked resource, please refer to the following code

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ManagementLockClient, ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.locks.models import LockLevel

compute_client=get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
lock_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ManagementLockClient)
resource_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ResourceManagementClient)

resource_group_name='jimtest'
vm=compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name=resource_group_name,vm_name='testvm')
# get os disk
os_disk=compute_client.disks.get(resource_group_name=resource_group_name,disk_name=vm.storage_profile.os_disk.name)
print("the vm os disk id is : "+os_disk.id)

#get data disk
for disk in vm.storage_profile.data_disks:
    data_disk = compute_client.disks.get(resource_group_name=resource_group_name, disk_name=disk.name)
    print("the vm data disk id is : " + data_disk.id)

#get nic
for nic in vm.network_profile.network_interfaces:
     print("the vm networkInterface id: ", nic.id)
     # get public ip, subnet,vent,nsg
     vm_nic = resource_client.resources.get_by_id(nic.id, api_version='2018-12-01')
     #get nsg
     print("the vm nsg id is :" + vm_nic.properties['networkSecurityGroup']['id'])
     for ipConfiguration in vm_nic.properties['ipConfigurations']:
         #get public ip
         print("the vm public ip id is :" + ipConfiguration['properties']['publicIPAddress']['id'])
         #get subnet
         id = ipConfiguration['properties']['subnet']['id']
         print("the vm subnet id is : " + id)
         #get vnet
         end = id.rfind('/', 0, id.rfind('/'))
         print("the vm vnet id is : " + id[0:end])
```

Comment: Thank you, any way to apply delete lock to VM resources if we have the VM name with us?

Comment: @udaykiran Could you please tell me what you mean VM resources?

Comment: Like all the disks, network nics, pulic ip address, everything linked to the machine.

Comment: @udaykiran If these resources are in the same group, we can implement it.

Comment: @udaykiran For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python#get-information-about-the-vm.

Comment: Yes in the same resource group mostly.But, the resource group may contain other machines also

Comment: I tried first code in "Get information about the VM" as in the link you shared, but getting this error  print("    createOption: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.create_option.value)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'.
Instead of individually pointing each element, is there any option to loop through all resources for the machine and apply a lock which we need.

Comment: @udaykiran I have provided a sample, please check it.

Comment: yes with the same sample code, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python#get-information-about-the-vm

Comment: @udaykiran Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: can't we get the resource group directly from the VM, as the code you shared asking to provide resource group as variable/parameter

Comment: @udaykiran If you just want to get the resource by VM name. You should list all vms in your subscription by code `compute_client.virtual_machines.list()` at first. Then do loop to get the vm you need.

Comment: If I know VMname, how to get the resource group name of that?

Comment: @udaykiran Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code `vm_name='testvm'
vms = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()
for vm in vms:
    if vm_name == vm.name :
        r = vm.id[1:(len(vm.id))].split('/')
        print("the vm resource group name is : " + r[3])`  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYEVJ.png

Answer (score 0):

No options for stop inheritance of create_or_update_at_resource_group_level().

While Lock can be applied on single resource level:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/release/v3/sdk/resources/azure-mgmt-resource/azure/mgmt/resource/locks/v2016_09_01/operations/_management_locks_operations.py#L430